# Free marker error: Left hand operand expected a number but this has evaluated to sequence + has+ string

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I am working in Netsuite advanced PDF, calculating MultipayTotal by subtracting  initial pay from gross amount but getting:

> **error Left-hand operand expected a number but this has evaluated to sequence + has+ string**

```
<#assign gross = 0 >
<#assign gross = transaction.total >
<#assign initialPayment = 0 >
<#assign initialPayment=transaction.custbody_pmnt_initialpayment>
<#assign multipayTotal = gross - initialPayment>
```

Comment: So `gross` is not a number then, which in turn means that `transaction.total` is not a number. Try `${gross}` and `${gross?keys?join(', ')}` to find out more about that value. (BTW, you miss the `-` from your example template. Also the initial `gross = 0` is needless.)

Comment: Thanks !  Could you please provide me full statement? have tried using ${gross} but still facing issues.

Comment: I don't know what value `gross` has, that's why I asked that two things. The error message also lacks information, but that's maybe because you are using some old FreeMarker. So I can only guess that it's from XML DOM query, and then you need `gross?number`.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the strings into numbers. Like this:

```
<#assign gross = transaction.total?number >
<#assign initialPayment=transaction.custbody_pmnt_initialpayment?number>
<#assign multipayTotal = gross - initialPayment>
```

For future reference, see other built-ins that freemarker has: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_number

Comment: Thanks, Wind, this solution doesn't work in my case. Posting error in sometime